# improve my accept rate

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Several respondents indicated to me that I should improve my accept rate, the problem is that I do not see anywhere where I can select a response given in my thread.
I've looked at the rules but do not see it in my thread.
I appreciate the help

Comment: There is a tickmark under the vote count for every single answer.  Try that.

Comment: Also note that comments that are asking you to improve your accept rate should be flagged.  They are noise and aren't accepted on Stack Overflow to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have to do is click the tick next to the best answer for your question

Here you have an image:

[image]